# Как высчитать значения для каждого?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код

```
<input name="itemName_0" value="Продукт №1" type="hidden">
<input name="itemQuantity_0" value="2" data-tinkoff-price="8400" type="hidden">
<input class="tnk__price" name="itemPrice_0" value="3000" type="hidden">


<input name="itemName_1" value="Продукт №2" type="hidden">
<input name="itemQuantity_1" value="1" data-tinkoff-price="11200" type="hidden">
<input class="tnk__price" name="itemPrice_1" value="3000" type="hidden">


<input name="itemName_2" value="Продукт№3" type="hidden">
<input name="itemQuantity_2" value="1" data-tinkoff-price="13000" type="hidden">
<input class="tnk__price" name="itemPrice_2" value="3000" type="hidden">
```

Как видно 3 раза повтоярется такая структура. Так вот у меня есть itemPrice - которая имеет value. Как можно высчитать для каждого value беря значения и предыдущего элемента tinkoff-price * quantyValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В метках вижу jQuery, хотя это можно организовать простейшим JS. Используйте `.each()` - он позволяет запускать функцию для каждого элемента. А первый аргумент этой функции является номером данного элемента. Этот же номер можно использовать, чтобы достать значения других инпутов (т.к. они расположены группами, рядом и в одинаковом порядке)

```js
$('.total').each(function( index ){

var qty = $('.itemqty').eq(index).val(); // Можно было и без переменных, прямо написать
var tnk = $('.tnk__price').eq(index).val(); // но так нагляднее.
$(this).val( qty * tnk  );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="total" name="itemName_0" value="Продукт №1">
<input class="itemqty" name="itemQuantity_0" value="2" data-tinkoff-price="8400">
<input class="tnk__price" name="itemPrice_0" value="3000">
<br>
<input class="total" name="itemName_1" value="Продукт №2">
<input class="itemqty" name="itemQuantity_1" value="1" data-tinkoff-price="11200">
<input class="tnk__price" name="itemPrice_1" value="3000">
<br>
<input class="total" name="itemName_2" value="Продукт№3">
<input class="itemqty" name="itemQuantity_2" value="1" data-tinkoff-price="13000">
<input class="tnk__price" name="itemPrice_2" value="3000">
```

Но учитывая type="hidden" вам скорее массивы нужны, чем инпуты... какая задача в итоге стоит?)